# How to modify and revert a simple Java Script loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, console

I'm learning basics of Java Script. I want to print the following in the console:

```
*2345
**345
***45
****5
*****
*****
****5
***45
**345
*2345
```

I've already wrote the code:
var x = 5;
var line;

```
for(var i = 0; i<x; i=i+1){
    line = "";
    for(var j=0; j<x; j=j+1){
        if(j <= i){
            line = line + " * ";
        }
    }
    console.log(line);
}
for(var i = x; i>0; i--){
    line = "";
    for(var j=0; j<x; j=j+1){
        if(j <= i-1){
            line = line + " * ";
        }
    }
    console.log(line)
}
```

So the result is:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Could anybody help me to modify the loop? I've tried various things but it never works.

Comment: Looks like an assignment question!

Comment: What conditions does your assignment set? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this for both the if conditions :

```
else {
line += j + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var baseString = "12345";
var starStrings = [];

for(var i = 0; i < baseString.length; i++){
  starStrings.push("*".repeat(i + 1) + baseString.slice(i + 1));
}
starStrings = starStrings.concat(starStrings.slice().reverse());

starStrings.forEach(function(s){
  document.write(s + "<br />");  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it like this:

```
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5],
    nLength = numbers.length,
    result = [],
    stringOf = function( value,times,str ) {

      if( 'undefined' === typeof str )
        str = '';

      if( times === 0 )
        return str;

      str += value;

      times--;

      return stringOf( value,times,str );

    },
    log = function( el ) { console.log( el ) };

for ( var i = 0; i < nLength; i++ ) {

  result[ i ] = stringOf( '*',i + 1 ) + numbers.slice( i + 1,nLength).join('');
  result[ i + nLength ] = stringOf( '*',nLength - i ) + numbers.slice( nLength - i,nLength).join('');

}

result.map( log );
```

Output:

```
*2345
**345
***45
****5
*****
*****
****5
***45
**345
*2345
```

Editing `numbers` array would change the output which will be in the same manner as specified.